# Create a restricted area for authenticated user only

Tags: ember.js

I've made a login system with Ember.js and Rails . So I tried to make redirection for non-authenticated users. I don't know where I must do the redirection (the application controller or in the application route ? ).
Here's my auth system :

```
window.AuthApp = Ember.Object.extend(Ember.Evented).create
authToken: null
currentUserId: null

signIn: (data) ->
    if data == null
        data = {}
    if data['remember'] == true
        cookie = true
    $.ajax 'api/login',
        type: 'POST'
        dataType: 'JSON',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
        error: ->
            alert('Error signIn')
        success: (data) ->
            console.log(data)
            AuthApp.set 'authToken', data['auth_token']
            if cookie == true
                $.cookie 'remember_token', data['auth_token'],
                    expires: 7

AuthApp.Module.RememberMe = Ember.Object.create
recall: ->
    if ($.cookie('remember_token'))
        data = {}
        data['auth_token'] = $.cookie('remember_token')
        AuthApp.signIn(data)
        return true
```

As you can see, I've just to call AuthApp.Module.Remember.recall() for check if an user is connected or not.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the router-facelift. One of the design goals was to make authentication-based apps less difficult to implement.

https://gist.github.com/machty/5723945